# How do I add a Javascript Object value to a HTML link

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a Javascript function that finds specific features from a JSON document and returns certain values from that feature to display the information in a popup (could be either a `confirm` or an `alert` function).

Each feature has a unique id which is a property that relates to an external database (the id for the feature is appended to a standard url, thus navigating to the relevant page on the database).

I would like to add a link into the popup so that the user can click and go through to the page that unique id code (i.e. for that particular feature) relates to.

The JSON:

```
var items = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [ { "type": "Feature", name: "Foo", "properties": {id: "1234"},{ "type": "Feature", name: "Bar", "properties": {id: "4321"} ]};
```

And the function, something along the lines of this (which isn't working):

```
function myFunction() {
    alert(feature.name + "<br>" + <a href="http://www.someurl.com/" + feature.properties.id>feature.properties.id</a>);
}
```

Comment: You're question is a little unclear. Can you add the code from the solutions you've tried so far?...

Comment: So, to summarize - you'd like to add unspecified information from JSON we can't see, to HTML you haven't shown, allowing click-throughs to links whose format is left as a mystery.

Comment: "I would like to add a link into the popup" You can't include (clickable) links in a confirm or alert popup.  You'll need to do this inside the DOM instead.

Comment: Give up on alert now before it's too late.  It's barely good for debugging since you can just use `console` and has no place in production code.

Comment: There are a lot of typos in your code, if this is the code you are really using, then there is not way it would work. For start, you say that `items` is JSON, well its not correct JSON, it can be a JS object literal and the way you are using it  in the function hints towards that as well. The `myFunction` function - the string inside the alert function -- is just not correct. Have you tried looking in the console, maybe?